# Expo React native new EAS build blank white screen after splash screen

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

So my app.js is literally copied and pasted from the react-navigation website. I get a blank white screen after the splash screen when using any of the createStackNavigator's including the createNativeStackNavigator and the same with the createBottomTabNavigator. the only one that works is the createMaterialBottomTabNavigator, all of the others show a blank screen. and when I do use the createMaterialBottomTabNavigator and embedded a stack navigator, when I click to that tab, the app crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the following packages solved this for me:

1. react-native-safe-area-context
2. react-native-screens
3. react-native-svg

The first two from [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x/) guide for upgrading to React Navigation 6.